# How to install android-rss library (org.mcsoxford.rss) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I don't understand the tutorial. I tried and searched for some help, but there is no normal tutorial how to install it in Eclipse.

Link: https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

I did the cmd command but I don't understand the last paragraph of the "Installation" section. What do I need to do with the `.classpath` file?

I've changed

`<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>`

to `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java/"/>` and I can use API methods in my code, but I have some exclamation mark on the project icon and I can't run my app.
Eclipse doesn't find any errors in my project files (Screenshot: http://pbrd.co/14ORkiL).

If someone can explain me how to make it work it will be great.

Thanks!